# Tensorflow CUDA GTX 1070 import error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, nvidia

I'm trying to install Tensorflow with CUDA support. Here are my specs:

- NVIDIA GTX 1070
- CUDA 7.5
- Cudnn v5.0

I have installed Tensorflow via the `pip` installation -- so I'm picturing your answer being to install from source, but I want to make sure there isn't a quick fix.

The error is:

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import test
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 77, in <module>
    import mock                # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top,unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mock.mock as _mock
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 71, in <module>
    _v = VersionInfo('mock').semantic_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 460, in semantic_version
    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/version.py", line 447, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 725, in get_version
    raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed?
```

I am running the `python` console from the home directory -- not in the Tensorflow directory.

GIT and CUDA both installed:

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~$ git --version
git version 2.5.0
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

I verified CUDA is functional via this test (found [here](https://github.com/saiprashanths/dl-setup)):

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/cuda-install-samples-7.5.sh ~/cuda-samples
cd ~/cuda-samples/NVIDIA*Samples
make -j $(($(nproc) + 1))
```

Tensorflow successfully installs:

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo -H pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

My GPU seems to be fine:

```
volcart@volcart-Precision-Tower-7910:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Aug  4 17:31:47 2016       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.35                 Driver Version: 367.35                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   41C    P8    12W / 185W |    499MiB /  8104MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       900    G   /usr/bin/X                                     272MiB |
|    0      1679    G   compiz                                         154MiB |
|    0      2287    G   ...s-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd    69MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Maybe try `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: `requirement already up to date`

Comment: Sounds like some kind of version mismatch, maybe try virtualenv install in fresh env?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov you da man! Thanks man that worked, I don't know why, but it worked. I've been working on this for too long lol. Feel free to write an answer, and I'll mark it correct

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I tried updating setuptools, did not work. I am using CentOS. I have the latest tensorflow, 1.0.0-rc1. It worked before, now it is messing up

Comment: argh, dependency hell! my solution when I hit these problems is to uninstall/reinstall larger and larger layers of software, I don't think I got any better at it after 2 years working with tensorflow/python/anaconda/virtualenv

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I get your point. I did the brutal way and removed every package in python in my GPU, installed tensorflow-gpu and got the same problem. Painful.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, it works now. I had to clean up everything and reinstall. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From error log, looks like some kind of version mismatch with mock or pbr packages, perhaps from an earlier install. In such cases building from source won't help, what you need is to install Python dependencies from scratch, ie, by using virtualenv install in new env

Answer (score 8):

Its a [bug in pbr](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pbr/+bug/1379579). The bug description contains a solution to export pbr version:

`export PBR_VERSION=X.Y.Z`

The pbr version can be get as `pbr -v`.

Comment: This also fixes the same error in Jenkins Job Builder

Comment: I am finding this problem now too. Can someone point to the solution for this?

Comment: That's it. Just export the pbr version it it should be enough

Comment: Fixed it for me

Comment: I'm having this problem just when distributing tensorflow with pyinstaller, https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2883, do I set pbr version before or after building the exe? I've tried building in a new virtual env, doesn't seem to effect anything.