# Error while running executable created by PyInstaller (python 2.7)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

Sorry for asking stupid questions.
I have packaged my python source code using Pyintaller (with Ubuntu 16.04 and pyinstaller 3.3.1). It runs perfectly on my own computers but get different errors. The typical error I got is

Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name mock was given, but was not able to be found.[1996] Failed to execute script predict".

The detailed error message is shown below. Please help me with this, i don't know how to fix it now. Many thanks!

```html
/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py:687: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "data_pre.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "csvdata_pre.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/test.py", line 61, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/mock/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-47BC1A/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "site-packages/pbr/version.py", line 462, in semantic_version
  File "site-packages/pbr/version.py", line 449, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
  File "site-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 812, in get_version
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name mock was given, but was not able to be found.
[49902] Failed to execute script predict
```

[image: here is the error message]

Comment: Your screenshot does not contain the complete error. The traceback is cut off. Please copy and paste the complete traceback into your question and put it in code formatting by pasting, then highlighting the whole traceback and then clicking the `{}` button

Comment: Hi @FlyingTeller  Thanks very much for your reply! This is my first time posting question on stackoverflow. Does it looks better now?:-) If there is any questions. Please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone has any idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: To be honest, I am a bit confused what the steps are that you have taken. "It runs perfectly on my own computers but get different errors. The typical error I got is"  - Does that mean it runs perfectly when executing the script you have written but no longer when you are trying to execute the version that comes out from pyinstaller? Also: Which dependencies do you have in your project?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thanks for your reply. I mean that I run the executable version coming from pyintaller perfectly in my own computer. But when I move the executable file to another computer, errors prompt out. Like the above error, or tensorflow not found or blahblah. All computers I ran are linux(Ubuntu Mint, CentOS), but they can not run it.

Comment: @FlyingTeller dependency I use in my program are Numpy, cPickle, Tensorflow, Keras and NLTK.

Comment: I found the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369902/how-to-package-tensorflow-with-pyinstaller-on-macosx